# Chess game advice

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am relativly new to programming and im starting an project of making a chess game. For now i only did 2 class
-Peice (nested class : Knight , Bishop , Pawn , Queen , King)
-Boeard (nested class : Position)

and finaly lead everything in the main form Screen.

For the moment i don't want to add piece movement or anything ...
My goal is to setting up a good root for making the chest game easier to programmer.
So im asking if any can give me some advice on how i could do this in a better way.

Im mostly focusing in Oriented object design and polymorphism

Form1 :

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Board board = new Board(new Point(25, 25));
    Peices peice = new Peices();


    public Form1()
    {      
      AllowTransparency = true;
      this.Controls.Add(board);
      //board.Controls.Add(p1);
      peice.putOnBoard(board);
      InitializeComponent();

    }
  }
```

Peice Class :

```
 class Peices
  {
      private List<PictureBox> peiceList = new List<PictureBox>();
      private static readonly Size PEICESSIZE = new Size(100,100);
      private static readonly Color PEICESBACKBROUDCOLOR  = Color.Transparent;



      private static Image _blackImage;
      public static Image blackImage
  {
    get { return _blackImage; }
    set { _blackImage = value; }
  }

      static Image _whiteImage;
      public static Image whiteImage
  {
    get { return _whiteImage; }
    set { _whiteImage = value; }
  }

      public Peices()
      {
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.A2 });
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.B2 });
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.C2 });
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.D2 });
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.E2 });
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.F2 });
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.G2 });
       peiceList.Add( new Pawn(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.H2 });
       peiceList.Add(new Knight(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.B1 });
       peiceList.Add(new Knight(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.G1 });
       peiceList.Add(new Bishop(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.C1 });
       peiceList.Add(new Bishop(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.F1 });
       peiceList.Add(new Rook(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.A1 });
       peiceList.Add(new Rook(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.H1 });
       peiceList.Add(new Queen(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.D1 });
       peiceList.Add(new King(Color.White) { Location = Board.Position.E1 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.A7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.B7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.C7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.D7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.E7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.F7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.G7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Pawn(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.H7 });
       peiceList.Add(new Knight(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.B8 });
       peiceList.Add(new Knight(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.G8 });
       peiceList.Add(new Bishop(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.C8 });
       peiceList.Add(new Bishop(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.F8 });
       peiceList.Add(new Rook(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.A8 });
       peiceList.Add(new Rook(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.H8 });
       peiceList.Add(new Queen(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.D8 });
       peiceList.Add(new King(Color.Black) { Location = Board.Position.E8 });      
      }
      public  void putOnBoard(Board board)
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < peiceList.Count; i++)
   {
     board.Controls.Add(peiceList[i]);
   }
  }
      static Image makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image pb)
 {
   Bitmap imgBitmap = (Bitmap)pb;
   imgBitmap.MakeTransparent(imgBitmap.GetPixel(0, 0));
   pb = imgBitmap;
   return pb;
 }
      public class Pawn : PictureBox
      {
        public Pawn( Color pawnColor)
        {
          blackImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("BlackPawn.bmp"));
          whiteImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("WhitePawn.bmp"));
          BackColor = PEICESBACKBROUDCOLOR;
          Size = PEICESSIZE;
          if (pawnColor == Color.Black) { Image = blackImage; }
          if (pawnColor == Color.White) { Image = whiteImage; }
        }       
    }
      public class Knight : PictureBox
      {
        public Knight(Color pawnColor)
        {
          blackImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("BlackKnight.bmp"));
          whiteImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("WhiteKnight.bmp"));
          BackColor = PEICESBACKBROUDCOLOR;
          Size = PEICESSIZE;
          if (pawnColor == Color.Black) { Image = blackImage; }
          if (pawnColor == Color.White) { Image = whiteImage; }
        }
      }
      public class Bishop : PictureBox
      {
        public Bishop(Color pawnColor)
        {
          blackImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("BlackBishop.bmp"));
          whiteImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("WhiteBishop.bmp"));
          BackColor = PEICESBACKBROUDCOLOR;
          Size = PEICESSIZE;
          if (pawnColor == Color.Black) { Image = blackImage; }
          if (pawnColor == Color.White) { Image = whiteImage; }
        }
      }    
      public class Rook : PictureBox
      {
        public Rook(Color pawnColor)
        {
          blackImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("BlackRook.bmp"));
          whiteImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("WhiteRook.bmp"));
          BackColor = PEICESBACKBROUDCOLOR;
          Size = PEICESSIZE;
          if (pawnColor == Color.Black) { Image = blackImage; }
          if (pawnColor == Color.White) { Image = whiteImage; }
        }
      }
      public class Queen : PictureBox
      {
        public Queen(Color pawnColor)
        {
          blackImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("BlackQueen.bmp"));
          whiteImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("WhiteQueen.bmp"));
          BackColor = PEICESBACKBROUDCOLOR;
          Size = PEICESSIZE;
          if (pawnColor == Color.Black) { Image = blackImage; }
          if (pawnColor == Color.White) { Image = whiteImage; }
        }
      }
      public class King : PictureBox
      {
        public King(Color pawnColor)
        {
          blackImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("BlackKing.bmp"));
          whiteImage = makeImageBackgroundInvis(Image.FromFile("WhiteKing.bmp"));
          BackColor = PEICESBACKBROUDCOLOR;
          Size = PEICESSIZE;
          if (pawnColor == Color.Black) { Image = blackImage; }
          if (pawnColor == Color.White) { Image = whiteImage; }
        }
      }
    }
```

Board Class :

```
class Board : Panel
{
  public static readonly Size BOARD_SIZE  = new Size(800,800);
  public static readonly int BOARD_ROW = 8;
  public static readonly int BOARD_COLUMN = 8;
  public static readonly Size BOARD_TILE_LENGTH = new Size((BOARD_SIZE.Height / BOARD_COLUMN), (BOARD_SIZE.Width / BOARD_ROW));
  private static readonly int BORD_PEICE_NUMBER = 64;

  public Board(Point locationPoint )
  {
    new Position();
    Size = BOARD_SIZE;
    Location = locationPoint;
    BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("ChestBord.png");
  }


  public class Position
  {
   static public Point A1;
   static public Point A2;
   static public Point A3;
   static public Point A4;
   static public Point A5;
   static public Point A6;
   static public Point A7;
   static public Point A8;
   static public Point B1;
   static public Point B2;
   static public Point B3;
   static public Point B4;
   static public Point B5;
   static public Point B6;
   static public Point B7;
   static public Point B8;
   static public Point C1;
   static public Point C2;
   static public Point C3;
   static public Point C4;
   static public Point C5;
   static public Point C6;
   static public Point C7;
   static public Point C8;
   static public Point D1;
   static public Point D2;
   static public Point D3;
   static public Point D4;
   static public Point D5;
   static public Point D6;
   static public Point D7;
   static public Point D8;
   static public Point E1;
   static public Point E2;
   static public Point E3;
   static public Point E4;
   static public Point E5;
   static public Point E6;
   static public Point E7;
   static public Point E8;
   static public Point F1;
   static public Point F2;
   static public Point F3;
   static public Point F4;
   static public Point F5;
   static public Point F6;
   static public Point F7;
   static public Point F8;
   static public Point G1;
   static public Point G2;
   static public Point G3;
   static public Point G4;
   static public Point G5;
   static public Point G6;
   static public Point G7;
   static public Point G8;
   static public Point H1;
   static public Point H2;
   static public Point H3;
   static public Point H4;
   static public Point H5;
   static public Point H6;
   static public Point H7;
   static public Point H8;

     public Position()
    {
      A1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      A2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      A3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      A4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      A5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      A6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      A7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      A8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*0, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);
      B1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      B2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      B3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      B4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      B5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      B6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      B7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      B8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*1, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);
      C1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      C2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      C3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      C4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      C5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      C6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      C7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      C8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*2, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);
      D1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      D2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      D3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      D4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      D5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      D6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      D7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      D8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*3, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);
      E1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      E2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      E3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      E4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      E5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      E6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      E7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      E8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*4, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);
      F1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      F2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      F3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      F4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      F5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      F6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      F7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      F8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*5, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);
      G1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      G2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      G3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      G4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      G5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      G6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      G7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      G8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*6, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);
      H1 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*1);
      H2 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*2);
      H3 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*3);
      H4 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*4);
      H5 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*5);
      H6 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*6);
      H7 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*7);
      H8 = new Point(BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width*7, BOARD_SIZE.Width - (BOARD_TILE_LENGTH.Width)*8);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: HMm it seems arrays will simplify your life here... your position class can have a 2d array that stores all the possible positions..

Comment: This is a code dump. You need to make your question more specific. Also, if you're relatively new to C#.. perhaps a Chess Engine is a bit advanced.

Comment: lol why my code is dump ? :P anyway .... i didnt put all those position in a 2darray cause i would like to call those position by an easy name .... not by an array Index ... but maybe i should put it in a attay ^^

Comment: @user3718713 A "code dump" in this context isn't commentary about the quality of the code, it's commentary that you've provided too much code, without a specific question. Stack Overflow is intended for answering specific questions, and ideally you only provide the code that is directly relevant to the question you're asking.

Comment: erf -_- sry if u dont like my presentation .... it my first post in stackoverflow :) maybe i will try to do better next time ^^

Comment: Separate... `peice.putOnBoard()` should not be in a GUI constructor. Also lookup the MVP (WinForms) or MVVM (WPF) patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would create a `BoardCoordinate` class which would handle all the board positioning logic, and allow you to access coordinates in multiple ways (numerically, and by id).

For example:

```
public class BoardCoordinate
{
    private const string[] xCoordId = new string[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};
    private const string[] yCoordId = new string[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};

    private Dictionary<string, Point> idToPoint;

    public BoardCoordinate()
    {
        idToPoint = new Dictionary<string,Point>();
        for(int i = 0; i < xCoordId.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < yCoordId.length; j++)
            {
                idToPoint.Add(xCoordId[i] + yCoordId[j], new Point(i,j));
            }
        }
    }

    public string getId(Point point)
    {
        return xCoordId[point.x] + yCoordId[point.y];
    }

    public Point getPoint(string id)
    {
        if(idToPoint.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            return idToPoint[id];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in a comment by icemanind, you want to separate logic from the display, hence why `BoardCoordinate` only deals with the actual integer coordinates as needed for the game  logic. You can easily have another class (your `Board` class, for instance) that will transform/multiply the coordinate by the proper amount to generate a visual coordinate. This is useful if, for example, you want to have both a 2d and a 3d visualization of your game. In this case, `Board2D` would transform the coordinate differently from `Board3D`, but `BoardCoordinate` would not require any changes.

If you'd like, you can create getters in the class for all the points by the full id (e.g. A1, A2, B1, etc.).

For example:

```
public Point A1 { 
    get { return getPoint("A1"); }
}
```

As it's just a helper class, you could choose to make it static as well.

As for the pieces, I would break that up into two types of classes, one for visual and one for logic, which would have an interface for each (e.g. `IPieceDisplay` and `IPieceLogic`).

The `IPieceLogic` interface might have some necessary methods which would be used for the logic of the game, such as:

```
public interface IPieceLogic
{
    PieceType pieceType { get; }
    boolean isAlive { get; }
    List<Point> getAvailableMoves();
    boolean canMoveTo(Point position);
    void moveTo(Point newPosition);
    Point getPosition();
    void die();
}
```

You would then implement a class for each type of `Piece`. You could theoretically use a single `PieceLogic` class. To do so, you would abstract out the movement logic for each piece, e.g. making a `MovementBehavior` interface/classes which would define how the pieces move, and `PieceLogic` would have an instance of some `MovementBehavior` used for all its calculations (e.g. `KnightMoveBehavoir`, `QueenMoveBehavior`, etc.).

`IPieceDisplay` might looks something like this:

```
public interface IPieceDisplay
{
    void animateTo(Point newPosition);
    void die();
    void select();
    void unselect();
    void draw();
    void setBitmap(Bitmap b);
}
```

Once again, you would implement a `PieceDisplay` class for each type of piece. For a very simple game, you could resort to using a single `PieceDisplay` implementation if none of the pieces require any unique visuals/animations/drawing logic.

Finally, you would then have a `Piece` class which would have an instance of both an `IPieceDisplay` and an `IPieceLogic`, and would handle both visual and logical updates to the pieces. Your `Board` (or perhaps a separate `BoardController` or `GameController` class) could then hold all the `Piece` instances, and would be responsible for the game flow, piece interactions, and user interactions.

Comment: Ty man your respond was RLYYYYYY helpfull :) i will work on it and repost the result if ur interested :D

Answer (score 0):

First piece of advice I can give you is [enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) are going to be your friend.

Most chess boards are 8x8 in size. That's 64 total squares. So first thing you'll want to do is make a piece class and enumeration, like this:

```
public enum PieceColors {
    Black,
    White
}

public enum PieceTypes {
    Rook,
    Pawn,
    Knight,
    Queen,
    King,
    Bishop
}

public class Piece {
    public PieceTypes PieceType { get; set; };
    public PieceColors PieceColor { get; set; };

    public Bitmap GetPieceBitmap()
    {
        // Return a Bitmap representing the piece based on PieceType and PieceColor
    }
}
```

And then a board class:

```
public class Board {
    public Piece[] Pieces { get; set; }

    public Board() {
         Pieces = new Piece[64];

         // Setup initial white pawns
         for (int x = 8; x < 16; x++)
         {
              Pieces[x].PieceColor = PieceColors.White;
              Pieces[x].PieceType = PieceTypes.Pawn;
         }
    }
}
```

Something like this should get you going!

Comment: is it possible to still call them by a name like A1 or somthing :P? but thx man ! i whil try this :D

Comment: and im not shure if my subclass is better or not .... cause with thiose class ... it would be easy to add the comportment of the peice in each ^^

Comment: @user3718713 Ubiquitous language is important in programming. Basically, we need to refer to the same concepts by the same names, otherwise chaos and confusion ensues. You're using the term "subclass" to refer to a *nested* class. A subclass is a class that is derived from a parent (or "base") class. In the code you provided above, your `Pawn` class is a subclass of `PictureBox`.

Comment: THX man that help me a lot! :) i will read on this subject :D

Comment: @user3718713 -- Make sure to always keep your logic and your GUI separate too. Your parent Pawn class (the logic) should not derive from PictureBox (your GUI)